# Replace just a part of files name with its folder name

Tags: python

I have some folders in `C:\Users\Documents\Datas`, whose names are A, B, C.

- Inside folder A: RE_20.csv ; RE_23.csv ; RE_25.csv
- Inside folder B: DF_41.csv ; DF_46.csv ; RE_47.csv
- Inside folder C: VN_81.csv ; VN_82.csv ; VN_89.csv

I want to replace just a part of `.csv` files with the name of its folder correspondent. I want to get:

- Inside folder A: A_20.csv ; A_23.csv ; A_25.csv
- Inside folder B: B_41.csv ; B_46.csv ; B_47.csv
- Inside folder C: C_81.csv ; C_82.csv ; C_89.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pathlib library was born for this sort of path manipulation.

Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

paths=Path('C:\\Users\\Documents\\Datas').glob('*/*.csv')

for path in paths:
    new_path = path.parent/re.sub('.+_',path.parent.name+'_',path.name)
    print(path,'->',new_path)
    path.replace(new_path)
```